# Make SVG cover entire viewport (responsive) and center SVG group object vertically and horizontally in viewport

Tags: svg, responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to configure a SVG to responsively cover the entire viewport. I've been able to do this using css and svg attributes but this method makes it difficult to achieve my secondary requirement. Inside the SVG i would like to horizontally/vertically center a  object.

--edit--

```
 <svg 
      version="1.1" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      x="0px" 
      y="0px"      
      style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:100"
      width="100%" 
      height="100%">     
      <rect 
        ref="introWhiteRec"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        fill="white"                          
      />
      <rect 
        ref="introBlackRec"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        fill="black"         
      />
      <rect
          ref="introBlackRec"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          fill="grey"/> <!-- center this h and v? -->                
    </svg>
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: You can find the center of your SVG canvas in user units using the `viewBox` attribute. Then you get the size of the object you want to center using `getBBox()`. Finally you translate the object the required amount to make the 2 centres coincide. Alternatively you may recalculate the coordinates of your object instead of translating. If you need more help please add some code.

Comment: Hi enxaneta, maybe I am missing something but viewbox cannot take percentages and so I am unable to define a viewbox that is responsive and takes up the entire viewport. When I define a viewbox="0 0 100 100" it creates a square. The user's viewport dimensions are unknown to me.

Comment: a viewBox is about what's inside the SVG, the height and width are its external size.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes that is correct.

Comment: If you have your viewBox as say "-50 -50 100 100" then the origin is the centre.

Comment: how do use viewbox and keep the svg response and taking up 100% width and height? While also maintaining perspective inside the viewbox? I'm not sure that it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is what you need:

```html
<svg 
      version="1.1" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      
      style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:100"
      width="100%" 
      height="100%">     
      <rect 
        ref="introWhiteRec"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        fill="white"                          
      />
      <rect 
        ref="introBlackRec"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        fill="black"         
      />
      <rect 
          ref="introBlackRec"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          x="-50"
          y="-50"
          style="transform: translate(50vw, 50vh)";
          fill="grey"/> <!-- center this h and v? -->                
    </svg>
```